# How can I add half a heart of health using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I add half a heart of health to a player when they are in a certain area?

I have got the detection part right I just don't know how to add exactly half a heart. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 effect @p 6
```

This heals the player too much though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a half hearth via instant health, however you could using regeneration for 3 seconds with level 1.

```
/effect @p minecraft:regeneration 3 0
```

This gives the player one half heart. For every 2,5 seconds the player gets half a heart.

Answer (score 2):

## Method A: For all users to use

To heal a player with this method exactly half a heart, set the score "Heal" on the player to 10. (Setting this on a loop will permanently give them regeneration until they disable the loop)

#### Commands in Chat

```
/scoreboard objectives add Heal dummy
```

#### Inside Command Blocks

(Note: All command blocks must be in line)
Repeating Command Block (Always Active, Unconditional)

```
scoreboard players remove @a[scores={Heal=0..}] Heal 1
Chain Command Blocks (Always Active, Unconditional)
execute as @a[scores={Heal=9}] run effect give @s regeneration 1 2 true
effect clear @a[scores={Heal=0}] regeneration
```

#### Recommended Commands In Chat

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

## Method B: For this specific example

To heal a player with this method exactly half a heart, stand on a Grass Block. Note if they stand off the Grass Block before they heal, they stop healing.

#### Commands in Chat

```
/scoreboard objectives add Heal dummy
/scoreboard objectives add HealAllow dummy
```

### Inside Command Blocks

(Note: All command blocks must be in line)
Repeating Command Block (Always Active, Unconditional)

```
execute as @a if block ~ ~-1 ~ grass_block run scoreboard players set @s HealAllow 1
```

Chain Command Blocks (Always Active, Unconditional)

```
scoreboard players set @a[scores={HealAllow=1}] Heal 10
scoreboard players set @a[scores={HealAllow=1}] HealAllow 2
execute as @a[scores={HealAllow=2}] unless block ~ ~-1 ~ grass_block run scoreboard players set @s Heal 1
execute as @a[scores={HealAllow=2}] unless block ~ ~-1 ~ grass_block run scoreboard players reset @s HealAllow
scoreboard players remove @a[scores={Heal=0..}] Heal 1
execute as @a[scores={Heal=9}] run effect give @s regeneration 1 2 true
effect clear @a[scores={Heal=0}] regeneration
scoreboard players set @a[scores={Heal=0}] HealAllow 1
```

### Recommended Commands In Chat

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

In Method B, if you wish to make them have to jump off the block to heal again, delete the last chain command block.